# Deploy asp.net core with ID 4 to Azure

Tags: c#

please help me to resolve this issue, I am trying to deploy my application included IdentityServer4 to Azure with subdomain (mysite.azurewebsites.net) but get this exception:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=altsourceaure.azurewebsites.net' on the 'CurrentUser\My'
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.SigningKeysLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(String subject, String storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, DateTimeOffset currentTime)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)

this is my configuration on Prd:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "My",
      "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
      "Name": "CN=mySite.azurewebsites.net"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample walk-through (for Azure AppService, Windows OS, not Linux) [Publish and deploy](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/docs/10-publish-and-deploy.md#setup-a-signing-certificate-with-azure-key-vault) on github (in one of the blazor workshops), maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @codeclash, I was having this issue with a Blazor WebAssembly Net Core hosted with Identity, followed walkthrough and now it is working, regards.

Comment: Having thesame issue but im in a shared hosting environment with my ssl from zerossl and hosting with interserver.net . its been days and im so stuck.